# SQL Server: one simple question

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I have a table `Transportation` with columns: `ClientIDAsSeller, ClientIDAsBuyer`..

and a `Client` table with column `ID` (Primary key). My C# app gets a client IDs and sets in the `Transportation` table.

When I press execute result is null

What is problem how can I solve that?

```
SELECT     
   Clients.Name, Transportation.TransStart, Transportation.TransEnd
FROM         
   Transportation 
INNER JOIN
   Clients ON Transportation.ClientIDAsSeller = Clients.ID 
              AND Transportation.ClientIDAsBuyer = Clients.ID
```

Comment: Does this return results if you execute the same exact query in SQL Management Studio or something similar? Your join may not be setup to pull the correct data, or you may need an outer join.

Comment: its show only column names below is nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely excluding all possible result sets by only doing one join.  You probably want to do:

```
SELECT
      S.Name as SellerName
      B.Name as BuyerName,
      Transportation.TransStart,
      Transportation.TransEnd
FROM Transportation
INNER JOIN
     Clients S
ON
     Transportation.ClientIDAsSeller = S.ID
INNER JOIN
     Clients B
ON
     Transportation.ClientIDAsBuyer = B.ID
```